# IDE that supports Java code assist in CFC?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

I was searching for an IDE that would provide content assist while working with Java objects in CFCs and couldnt' find any. Does someone know of an IDE or if this feature exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Not _exactly_ what you're looking for, but [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) is a Java IDE that also has plugin support for CFML. Might be worth a look.

Comment: I doubt it. I am not aware of any tools that provide *java* code insight from within a *ColdFusion* editor. Though if such a thing did exist I would be curious to try it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. java code assist from within CFCs would be really handy and I am surprised something like this is not out there yet.

Comment: I am not 100% positive, just that I have never come across one personally. I suspect it would be problematic as there is there is bound to be a lot of overlapping between cfscript and java. Especially with extended support in CF9+.